# change default hibernate mapping strategy for enums

Tags: hibernate, enums, mapping, default

When using Hibernate, the dafault mapping strategy for enums is ORDINAL. Because I think the STRING strategy is more robust, I want to change the default mapping strategy to favor that.

Currently I have to use the following on any enum:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(nullable=false)
private MyEnum myEnum;
```

Is there a way to tell hibernate to always use the STRING strategy? My research did not come up with some property that allows to change this behaviour.

Or is it impossible because JPA specifies ORDINAL as default and we should explicitly annotate it to stay O/R-Mapper neutral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with you that `EnumType.STRING` is more robust especially when refactoring source code as chaging order of constants in enum is often done by inadvertance (or simply because someone sorts them alphabeticaly).

But you also right that there is no way to change the default behaviour, as ORDINAL mapping has been defined as default by design (may be because a Numeric Column is more efficient than a varchar typed column).

Comment: Nine years later still no way to change the default to `STRING` with some Hibernate configuration property?